# python-Levenshtein.ratio calculation

Tags: python, levenshtein-distance

I have two strings:

```
>>> a= '@ROAD INC'
>>> b = 'WYETH'
>>> Levenshtein.ratio(a, b)
0.0
```

Now I understand the calculation behind it, but not the intuition:

```
>>> ldist = sum([2 for item in Levenshtein.editops(a,b) if item[0] == 'replace']) 
              + sum([1 for item in Levenshtein.editops(a,b) if item[0] != 'replace'])
>>> ln = len(a) + len(b)
>>> ldist - ln
0
```

Isn't the result counter-intuitive? Shouldn't lower Levenshtein.ratio be interpreted as string match instead of complete string difference?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand; what is counter-intuitive? `Levenshtein.ratio` *is* interpreted as string match: `0.0` means "no match".

Comment: Ah. My bad. You are right. Not sure what I was thinking.